# SQL: Substitute values between columns

Tags: sql, oracle, substitution

I have a (very simplified) (Oracle) table like this. The row number are only for better understanding, they have no deeper meaning.

| Row | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Mike |

Now I find the "error" - the names are messed up. All "Jims" should be renamed to "John", John changes to Mike and Mike changes to Jim.

My first update changes Jim to John.
My second update should change John to Mike.

But the real problem is: Now I have two Johns - the old and the renamed Jim. How to find and modify the "old John" without changing the other?

My idea is to use temp-values:

- Jim to temp_John
- John to temp_mike
- Mike to Jim
- temp_John to John
- temp_mike to Mike

Good idea? Or are there better ones? Or is it the totally wrong way?

Edit:
I reality, there are not three names, but 700 - 1000 numbers, so
25 to 345
558 to 2
1 to 38
...

Answer (score 0):

Nah, it's just a single `UPDATE` with a `CASE` expression:

```
SQL> select * From test order by crow;

      CROW VALU
---------- ----
         1 Jim
         2 John
         3 Mike

SQL> update test set
  2    value = case when value = 'Jim'  then 'John'
  3                 when value = 'John' then 'Mike'
  4                 when value = 'Mike' then 'Jim'
  5            end;

3 rows updated.

SQL> select * From test order by crow;

      CROW VALU
---------- ----
         1 John
         2 Mike
         3 Jim

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks; I think this will also work for the reality with some hundred numbers.

Comment: It'll work for *any* number of names (unless it exceeds 255; in that case, either write another UPDATE or nest CASE expressions). The same limit exists for DECODE function, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decode`:

```
update test set value = decode(value,'JIM','JOHN','JOHN','MIKE','MIKE','JIM');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=63207cd0abf973bed149402ece154ee2)*

For numbers you can use negative numbers as a temporarity:

```
update test value = decode(value, 65537, -7777776777777, value);
update test value = decode(value, 7777776777777, -45, value);
update test value = decode(value, 45, -65537, value);
update test set value = abs(value);
```

This way you can have as many numbers as you want as it uses one query per number.

*updated db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3f04be863937802950b0a787695eabc7) for numbers example*

Comment: Thanks; I think this will also work for the reality with some hundred numbers.

Comment: Oops - "decode" is limited: "The maximum number of components in the DECODE function, including expr, searches, results, and default, is 255. "

Comment: numbers are a different matter. if you only use positive numbers, you can set each "new" number to a negative value, then at the end make them all positive.

Comment: Thanks; I think this is similar to my "temp_value idea"

Comment: I suppose, but a small difference that you will remove all the "temp_" at once in the end:
Jim to temp_John, 
John to temp_mike, 
Mike to temp_Jim, 
substitute 'temp_' with '' (nothing)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table with two columns:

```
create table value_pairs
(old_value integer,
 new_value integer,
 primary key (old_value));
```

After creating the table you have to insert the old and new values:

```
insert into value_pairs values (1, 2);
insert into value_pairs values (2, 3);
etc.
```

Finally run this SQL statement:

```
update your_table t
   set value =
(select new_value
   from value_pairs p
  where p.old_value = t.value);
```

In this case you don't have to write long case or decode statements.

Comment: Thanks, looks good too. But nevertheless I have to define every INSERT condition (for 'Jim to John' and so on - see above)